# Need help on: CodeGear.Cpp.Targets(3907,5): error MSB6006: "id" exited with code 1

Tags: delphi, c++builder, c++builder-10.3-rio

On compileing i get an error:

> codegear.cpp.targets(3907,5): error MSB6006: "id" exited with code 1

I got an similar error before and fixsd it whit this link: https://community.idera.com/developer-tools/platforms/f/android-platform/67500/unable-to-upgrade-project-from-10-2-3-to-10-3/83846#83846
but it does not seem to work whot this problem. Cant find any information on

> (3907,5)

either.

Comment: I suggest you file a support request at Embarcadero to fix the problem.

Comment: MSB is *MicroSoft Build*. This means that the error comes from MSBuild.exe when attempting to build your app. It's not a Delphi or C++ Builder error.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was a function that used windows.h to determine datetime